# Is there any way to keep a video stream active in PHP?

Tags: php, video-streaming

I'm setting up a video streaming website for me and my friends to watch movies together online.

I've tried using https://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial and it works fine to load up a video.

// All the code is available in the link above.

The problem I'm facing is that I want the stream to run independently. Without everyone starting from 0:00 when they refresh or log onto the page. Is there any way in PHP to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial you're trying to use is pretty awful.  There is *zero* need for PHP in this case.  The web server itself can handle ranged requests just fine.  And, the idea of streaming from an S3 bucket?  Just sign a URL!  Don't double your bandwidth usage and slow everything down by proxying that data from S3 back through your application server.  Don't use this tutorial, it's bad.  More importantly, it doesn't solve your use case.

> The problem I'm facing is that I want the stream to run independently. Without everyone starting from 0:00 when they refresh or log onto the page. Is there any way in PHP to do that?

There are a couple ways to handle this.  One of which is to use static file hosting for the video files, then schedule when they're supposed to play, and use some JavaScript to seek into the video file at the right point.

For example, suppose I know that TheMatrix.mp4 is supposed to start at 12:00 PM, and it's currently 12:15 PM.

```
const videoEl = document.querySelector('video');
videoEl.currentTime = 15 * 60; // 15 minutes
```

You could create some form of a playlist to track this.

Alternatively, you can encode a live stream where everyone receives the same packets at the same time.  To do this, look into [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Icecast) as a source encoder, and [Icecast](http://icecast.org/) as a server.